# justify in vertically tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

when I write in a label, and the height of the text is greater than that of the label, I would like to know if there is a way to justify it vertically because otherwise the text gets weird, icant upload images, so basically this one has 3 of height. but when there are 4 lines of text, all 4 are shown, but half of the first and half of the fourth, I would like only 3 to be shown

```
   I_Text_Box                 = PIL.Image.open(Text_Box)
        I_Text_Box                 = I_Text_Box.resize((350,int(350*712/800)), PIL.Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        I_Text_Box_Image           = ImageTk.PhotoImage(I_Text_Box)
        
        Flag_Text_Box = True
        
        ventana_BT = tk.Toplevel()
        ventana_BT.title("Ventana Text Box")
        
        if main.winfo_rootx() > 1500:
            ventana_BT.geometry("350x350+"+str(main.winfo_rootx()-80)+"+"+str(main.winfo_rooty()-45))
            izquierda = True
        else:
            ventana_BT.geometry("350x350+"+str(main.winfo_rootx()+60)+"+"+str(main.winfo_rooty()-45))
            izquierda = False
        
        ventana_BT.configure(background="gray")
                
        Box_Texto = tk.Label(ventana_BT, image = Cambiar_Image_Dialogo(None), bg="gray")
        Box_Texto.place(x=0, y =0)
           
        # Agregar texto
        text_var = tk.StringVar()
        label = tk.Label(ventana_BT, textvariable=text_var, font=("Console", 15), bg="pink", width=17, height=3, justify="left")
        
        if not izquierda:
            label.place(x=70, y=125)
        else:
            label.place(x=80, y=125)
                        
        #Box_Texto.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: Abrir_Ventana_Texto(None))
        #chat_str = "amigos"
              

        ventana_BT.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution:

anchor have multiple options,
NW
N
NE
W
CENTER
E
SW
S
SE
being s=south, n=north, e=east, w=west and center and so you can justify the way you want

```
label = tk.Label(ventana_BT, textvariable=text_var, font=("Console", 15), bg="pink", width=17, height=2, justify="left", anchor="sw")
```

Comment: Does this actually answer the question, or is it a clarification to your question? If it's an answer, I would edit this answer to make that clearer, and if it's a clarification to your question, it really should be an edit to the question instead.

Comment: its a answer, Sorry I don't know how I should clarify, I'm new to stackoverflow